# How can I stop minimised windows from getting highlighted when I hover over them in Lubuntu?

Tags: lubuntu, lxde

As you can see in the image, the software minimized window is highlighted (bold text) since my mouse is hovering on it. How do I stop this text highlighting?

[image]

Comment: [This Lubuntu tutorial](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Lubuntu/Windows#Changing_running_applications_in_panel_to_icons_only) explains how to display icons only for minimized windows in the taskbar, but I am not sure this is what you are asking for.

Comment: The main answer to [this question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/149540/lxde-active-window-in-lxpanel-task-bar-window-list-plugin-is-indistinguishabl#163768) suggests that the only option is to patch lxpanel. Once more, I doubt this actually answers your question.